# hide div if no check boxes are checked

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

Okay... I will try to simplify this example. What I have is a form with some dynamically created check boxes. This form will be used to insert new records as well as edit existing records. What I would like to do is have a script that checks checkboxes on page load. IF their are zero checked checkboxes then the div that has the button will be hidden. Once the user checks a checkbox, then the button will show. Here is the code that I have.

jQuery

```
if ($(".uniForm input:checkbox:checked").length > 0) {
    $(".buttonHolder").show(); // any one is checked
} else {
    $(".buttonHolder").hide(); // none is checked
}
```

Coldfusion / HTML

```
<cfform ACTION="about:blank" name="formSend" class="uniForm">

   <cfset i = 1>

     <cfloop query="qRooms">

        <cfif variables.active is 1>

               <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_#i#" name="app_#ApplianceTypeID#_chk" style="width:50px" checked>

        <cfelse>

                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_#i#" name="app_#ApplianceTypeID#_chk" style="width:50px">

        </cfif>

     </cfloop>

</cfform>

 <div class="buttonHolder" id="buttonfield">
       <button type="submit" class="secondaryAction" onClick="window.location='index-10.cfm'; return false;">Cancel and go back</button>
        <button type="submit" class="primaryAction">Submit</button>
 </div>
```

I think I am close... hust a little confused on the .change event.

Comment: is there any question here ?

Comment: Hm.. which task is causing difficulty? a) Hide/Show the `<div>` when the page loads or b) showing the `<div>` when any one of the boxes is checked ?

Comment: Unless there is a conflict in my code not shown here, the button hides on load but doesn't show once any of the check boxes are checked.

Comment: I set up a jsFiddle... new to it so I hope it helps. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a876u/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead :

```
if($('.uniform').find('input:checked').length > 0)
```

`find()` is faster and `:checkbox` is not a working selector (or I am not awar of this one), I think you meant `input[type=checkbox]:checked`, but in your scenario, it is not needed since you have no radio button (the only other input who can be `:checked`).

Hope it helped!

Comment: I set up a jsFiddle... new to it so I hope it helps. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a876u/)

Comment: FYI click or change event wont matter and if you have multyple input, just used the selector I used in the answer to select only inputs with checkbox type

Comment: knocked it out the park! Thanks Karl!

Answer (score 0):

the `.change()` event is used more to get the actual value of `slider`, `radio` buttons or `<select>` tags and in `jQuery` you have to use `.class` to select element by class or `#id` to select by ID